# How to "freeze" armature bone transforms like in Maya (to export to Unity)

Tags: armature, export, transforms, .fbx

I'd like to ask if there's a way to "freeze" the transforms of every bone in an armature (setting their localPos = 0,0,0, localRot = 0,0,0, localScale = 1,1,1) without modifying their actual 3D location, the same way Maya does ?? My problem is that, I've tried "Applying" (Ctrl + A) Transforms and All Transforms to Deltas to the armature but when exporting as FBX and opening in Unity, the bones are not frozen (their pos/rot/scale don't have identity values)

Does any one know how to do this ? Thanks immensely in advance